# Getting error while using (/) division operator in perl cgi?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am using following function to calculate number of days. The argument to the setAge function is epoc time.

```
 sub getAge {
    my $diff;
    my $age=0;
    my $sec=86400;
    my $createTime;
    my $currTime;
    $createTime = $_[0];
    $currTime = UnixDate("now", "%s");
    $diff = ($currTime - $createTime);
    $age =(($diff-($diff%$sec))/$sec);
    return $age;
 }
```

But whenever I am using the division operator I am getting the below error

```
syntax error at /apollo/env/ShiftReport/server-root/gcShiftReport.cgi line 616, near ")
    {"
syntax error at /apollo/env/ShiftReport/server-root/gcShiftReport.cgi line 618, near "case 'OX-Gift-Hyderabad'"
Execution of /apollo/env/ShiftReport/server-root/gcShiftReport.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The error line is coming from the immediately following function definition.

```
sub getName {
    my $tempName = $_[0];
    switch ($tempName)
    {
            case 'Cart Software' { return 'CART' }
            case 'OX-Gift-Hyderabad' { return 'Gift' }
            else { return $_[0]}
    }
}
```

Can somebody give some pointer on why this is happening and only when I am using the division (/) operator.

Comment: So change the `/` to a `*` and *change nothing else* -- what happens? Still think it's related to the operator? Also ... spaces,  please :(

Comment: I changed / to a * and it's working

`$age =(($diff - ($diff%$sec)) * $sec);`

Comment: That is ... very odd. Well, you've sparked my +1 interest.

Comment: If you want to do date math, use a module such as DateTime. You won't have this syntax error or the math error that today (of all days in the US at least) would have created.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, you are using the deprecated [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) module. You have probably forgot to add `use Switch`, hence the `switch` keyword is not imported. If you want this functionality, you should use `use feature qw(switch)` instead, which uses the keywords `given`, `when` and `default` instead.

Your error message - which is rather vague - comes of perl not processing `switch ($variable) { ... }` as a valid statement. The compiler thinks it sees a function, because of the bareword `switch` followed by parens, but the following block `{ ... }` causes the error.

This has nothing to do with the code that precedes it, and the code works for me if I add `use Switch`.

It is debatable if using this particular feature for this code is a good choice.

```
use feature qw(switch);

sub getName {
    my $tempName = $_[0];
    given ($tempName)
    {
            when ('Cart Software') { return 'CART' }
            when ('OX-Gift-Hyderabad') { return 'Gift' }
            default { return $_[0]}
    }
}
```

The equivalent, without relying on switch:

```
sub getName {
    my $name = shift;
    return "CART" if $name eq "Cart Software";
    return "Gift" if $name eq "OX-Gift-Hyderabad";
    return $name;
}
```

I think this is preferable, as it is clearer which type of comparison is made.

**ETA:** Your subroutine getAge can be written much more efficiently. I took the liberty of removing your random capitalisations, because they are evil, and perl does actually differentiate between `aFunctionForGettingStuff` and `aFunctionForgettingStuff`.

I see that you are using some kind of homemade way of truncating a float. This is not necessary, as perl does have a built-in function that does that: [int()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html)

```
sub getage {
    my $createtime = shift; # shift first argument off @_
    my $sec = 86400;
    # use int() instead of removing remainder
    my $age = int((UnixDate("now", "%s") - $createtime) / $sec);
    return $age;
}
```

It's not necessary to stack the statements into one, but I think it is a good idea to remove as many transition variables as possible. I do, however, feel it is necessary - from a readability point of view, and good practice - to not declare variables until you actually use them. That way, when you read the code and see `my $foo = ...` you *know* that `$foo` is declared and assigned then and there.

You could even remove the `$age` variable, but I feel it does add something to readability to leave it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using `use warnings` and `use strict`. The entire code was working fine till the time I didn't introduce the new function `sub getAge`. And as I mentioned in the above comment every other operator is working fine but `/`.

Comment: @TLP: The OP is using the deprecated [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Switch-2.16/Switch.pm) module which was replaced in 5.10.0 [perl5100delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html)

Comment: @JRF or, more accurately, the OP *isn't* using the `Switch` module. Hence the errors.

Comment: @KumarGaurav It is virtually impossible that the operator `/` is causing your errors. More likely, you have changed something else. My advice: Don't use switch or given, instead use the if statements I showed in my answer. If the problem remains, let us know.

Comment: @Borodin OK. I guess I should have said "appears to be trying to use".  My point was the syntax would be valid if the OP **was** using the deprecated module.

Comment: @JRFerguson Ah, thanks. I knew there was something like that, I just drew a blank.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are missing

```
use Switch;
```

from the start of your program. But this is the old version of the `switch` statement. If you are using a Perl version 5.10 or later you can replace this with

```
use feature 'switch';
```

described [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html). The syntax uses `given`/`when`/`default` instead of `switch`/`case`/`else`, and the `when` conditions need parentheses around them, just like an `if` condition. Your code should become

```
sub getName {
  my $tempName = $_[0];
  given ($tempName) {
    when  ('Cart Software') { return 'CART' }
    when ('OX-Gift-Hyderabad') { return 'Gift' }
    default { return $_[0]}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` module is implemented as a source filter, it reads your source code and attempts to translate `switch` statements into valid Perl code. My guess is that it somehow you managed to convince `Switch` that the `/` starts a regular expression match, hiding your `switch` in what it thinks is pattern text. In this case your `switch` is trivial to rewrite as a hash look up that is likely both safer and faster.

```
my %name_map = (
    'Cart Software' => 'CART',
    'OX-Gift-Hyderabad' => 'Gift',
);
sub getName {
    my $temp_name = $_[0];
    if (exists $name_map{$temp_name}) {
        return $name_map{$temp_name};
    }
    return $temp_name;
}
```